# How to change the standard href="#" attribute of h:commandLink?

Tags: jsf-2, mojarra

I am maintaining a JSF2 Ajax application and we are heavily using `h:commandLinks` and `f:ajax` tags for all actions - always only rerendering what is needed.

This does of course break the expected behaviour for the user when performing a right click on the links and choosing "Open Link in New Tab" etc.

I understand that f:ajax forces the href atribute of the resulting `a` element to be `#` and does all the magic post request trickery in the onclick function - I now want to provide fallback support for the "Open Link..." action by putting some meaningful link in the href attribute of the resulting `<a>` tag.

This would not break the "normal" onclick behaviour as the generated javascript always finishes with `return false;` but would allow me to send my users to some page using a normal GET request in case they want to open the link in a new window.

Is there a build in way to do this? Or could somebody point me in the right direction on where in the JSF lifecycle I would have to jump in to do this maybe using a phase listener?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest would be to extend [`com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.CommandLinkRenderer`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.sun.faces/jsf-impl/2.1.0/com/sun/faces/renderkit/html_basic/CommandLinkRenderer.java) and override the [`renderAsActive()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.sun.faces/jsf-impl/2.1.0/com/sun/faces/renderkit/html_basic/CommandLinkRenderer.java#CommandLinkRenderer.renderAsActive%28com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.FacesContext,com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.UIComponent%29) method accordingly. Mojarra is open source, just copy the method and edit the line where it says [`writer.write("href", "#", "href")`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.sun.faces/jsf-impl/2.1.0/com/sun/faces/renderkit/html_basic/CommandLinkRenderer.java#214). Replace the `"#"` string accordingly to your insight.

```
public class MyCommandLinkRenderer extends CommandLinkRenderer {

    @Override
    protected void renderAsActive(FacesContext context, UIComponent command) throws IOException {
        // ...
    }

}
```

To get it to run, register it as follows in `faces-config.xml`:

```
<render-kit>
    <renderer>
        <component-family>javax.faces.Command</component-family>
        <renderer-type>javax.faces.Link</renderer-type>
        <renderer-class>com.example.MyCommandLinkRenderer</renderer-class>
    </renderer>
</render-kit>
```

Note that this tight couples your renderer to Mojarra. To be JSF implementation independent, you'd need to create a whole new renderer instead of extending a Mojarra specific renderer class.

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, consider reading [When should I use h:outputLink instead of h:commandLink?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317684/when-should-i-use-houtputlink-instead-of-hcommandlink)

Comment: thank you BalusC, extending the CommandLinkRenderer worked perfectly to achieve the desired result.